# Only use translations from messages.php in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to load all our translations into a flat array in `resources/lang/en/messages.php` and `resources/lang/fr/messages.php`

I would like to translate them in the view simply with `trans('key')` rather than `trans('file.key')`

Anyway to enable this behaviour? Seems it does not come out of the box. Thanks.

Comment: You could make your own helper that just calls `trans('messages.' . $key)`.

Comment: Yeah good point, but in this case I want to continue to use the `trans` function

Comment: Well, `trans()` is defined in the core code, but it's wrapped in an `if(!function_exists()) { }` block, so you can override it by mimicking its functionality in your own `function trans()` that gets loaded before the main helpers.

Comment: no its not possible, that function is defined extremely early, it's loaded in index.php in `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`

Comment: So define yours before that. Or suck it up and use a different function name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how, first define your own provider in App\Providers. Have it use your own custom class instead.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use App\Utilities\TranslationUtility;
use Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider;

class SimpleTranslationProvider extends TranslationServiceProvider {

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->registerLoader();

    $this->app->singleton('translator', function($app)
    {
        $loader = $app['translation.loader'];

        $locale = $app['config']['app.locale'];

        $trans = new TranslationUtility($loader, $locale);

        $trans->setFallback($app['config']['app.fallback_locale']);

        return $trans;
    });
}

}
```

Custom class:

```
<?php namespace App\Utilities;

use Illuminate\Translation\Translator;

class TranslationUtility extends Translator {

    public function get($key, array $replace = array(), $locale = NULL)
    {
        return parent::get('messages.' . $key);
    }
}
```

Then add your service provider in config/app.php instead of `'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider'`